# Regarding Linux Kernel Pagetable

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

I'm currently working on linux kernel version 5.10.39. I am trying to boot linux kernel on arm a-78 cpu core.

It's successfully execute the instructions which is in head.s file...
But get stuck on one instruction which is cmp x9, x10 in __relocate_kernel fuction.

Where to i stuck in function which is define below.

SYM_FUNC_START_LOCAL(__relocate_kernel)

```
ldr w9, =__rela_offset  // Offset for the reloc table   
ldr w10, =__rela_size   // Size of the reloc table  

mov_q   x11, KIMAGE_VADDR       // default virtual offset
add x11, x11, x23           // actual virtual offset
add x9, x9, x11         // __va(.rela)
add x10, x9, x10            // __va(.rela) + sizeof(.rela)

cmp x9, x10
b.hs    1f
ldp x12, x13, [x9], #24
ldr x14, [x9, #-8]
cmp w13, #R_AARCH64_RELATIVE
b.ne    0b
add x14, x14, x23           // relocate
str x14, [x12, x23]
b   0b
```

What's the solution for this ?
Is this Pagetable fault ?

Comment: What do you mean, "get stuck"?  What actually happens, and how do you know it's on that specific instruction?

Comment: Hii Nate Eldredge.. 

we are testing with our system with an emulator, built on the system itself
The system do have a UART, but it is not fully functional for now, as the driver part is under development.
Until than, we are debugging the kernel execution by printing single characters on UART (by writing directly on UART transmitter register memory)
That's how we came to know this.

Actually we can not say this is stuck but, It stays in loop , When cpu execute this function which is define above on question ...

Comment: Do x9 and x10 have sensible values, and is there a reasonable-looking relocation table in that region of memory?

Comment: Hii , 
As you can see in above code, x9 = __rela_offset value and x10 = __rela_size.
But we are not sure about the values.
and so, we need some help here.

Comment: Could you change that code so it contain actual instruction addresses ? the only reason, I see, that `cmp x9, x10` fails is that's a first instruction on not-mapped memory page. Pretty sure it's not a case though...

Comment: Do you  have a breakpoint set on that instruction?

Comment: Hii stark, 
No any breakpoint is there...